# Why String.intern() behave differently in Oracle JDK 1.7?

Tags: java, string

Here is a java snippet:

```
public class TestIntern {
    public static void main(String[] argvs){
        String s1 = new StringBuilder("ja").append("va").toString();
        String s2 = new StringBuilder("go").append("lang").toString();
        System.out.println(s1 == s1.intern());
        System.out.println(s2 == s2.intern());
    }
}
```

And It behave different according to different JDKs

in Oracle JDK 1.7 output is:

```
false
true
```

in OpenJDK 1.6 output is also:

```
false
true
```

but in Oracle JDK 1.6 output is:

```
false
false
```

as the JavaDoc for this `String#intern` method indicates

```
 * When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a
 * string equal to this <code>String</code> object as determined by
 * the {@link #equals(Object)} method, then the string from the pool is
 * returned. Otherwise, this <code>String</code> object is added to the
 * pool and a reference to this <code>String</code> object is returned.
                           ~~~~
                             And what does *this* here mean? the string object
                             in the heap or in the string pool? if it returns 
                             object in the heap the out put should be:

                             true
                             true
                             otherwise should *always* be:

                             false
                             false
                             Am I right?
```

the output:

```
true
true
```

should be expected, but neither three JDKs produce this. and Why Oracle JDK1.6 gives:

```
false
false
```

as a result?

I think in OracleJDK 1.7 and openJDK 1.6 there must be some *reserved* string in the string pool, and what are they? is there a document specify all the *reserved* strings?
Really confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not `s1.intern()` returns `s1` or some other `String` object depends on what it finds in the interned strings pool. If there's already some other `String` object in the pool, `intern()` will return that other object; otherwise it will put the `String` object referenced by `s1` into the pool and return that same object.

The issue is not the that different Java versions behave differently, it is that the pools happened to contain different things when you ran your tests. I don't find it particularly surprising that the pools in Oracle JDK 1.7 and openJDK 1.6 happened to already contain the string `"java"` but not the string `"golang"`.

Comment: String `java` could be a *reserved* key word in the internal string pool, but I find String `ja` is also behaving the same, what kind of *keyword* is that stand for? and why jvm contains `ja` before anything happens?

Comment: And what do you mean by **that** in parse "put the `String` object referenced by `s1` ... and return **that** object.", does **that** means object in the heap we build or the object in the pool just added?

Comment: @armnotstrong - Take your pick; they are one and the same object. That's the whole point.

Comment: with all my respect,but I don't understand what do you mean by "they are the same object", do you mean that the string pool only store the reference of the string and the value of that string is stored in the heap?

Comment: @armnotstrong - Exactly. All objects in Java are on the heap. When I say "return that same object", I mean that it returns a reference to the same object. (I apologize for the slightly sloppy wording, but I thought this was understood: all values in Java are either primitive values or object references; they are never objects themselves.)

Comment: thanks, that really clear my confusion, but still, I don't understand why Oracle JDK 1.6 gives both `false`, I don't understand for any reason `golang` should exists in the string pool beforehand. I think that must be some reason related to the string pool implement changing, I will dig in to it and see what can I get. Thanks again for your patient.

Comment: @armnotstrong - Yes, it is very weird that Oracle JDK 1.6 printed `false` for `"golang"`. The only explanation I can think of is that somehow that string was already interned. Perhaps the code was run once before in the same JVM instance?

Comment: I have post some idea about why JDK 1.6 always return `false`, think you maybe want to review it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I think I figured out all the confusions in this issue, and should make a summary.

This is a complementarity answer with @Ted answer, in his Post.
He point out that it is what the program finds in the string pool that affect the result of `s1 == s1.intern()` returns. It perfectly explained the behavior of Oracle JDK 1.7 and the OpenJDK, but not the weird behavior of Oracle JDK 1.6, which will always return `false`,regardless of whatever `s1` is.

I think why Oracle JDK 1.6 always return `false` is because of this **internal string pool** was in the permanent generation but [was transferred to heap](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6962931) in JDK 1.7. So in JDK 1.6 string object on the heap and in the permanent generation will never be the same object.

To Prove this, I write a java program and run it under Oracle JDK 1.6

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestIntern {
    public static void main(String[] argvs){
       String s1 = null; // string inputed
       String s2 = null; // string retrieved by string.intern() in this loop
       String s3 = null; // string retrieved by string.intern() in last loop
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Enter the string");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                     new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            try {
                s1 = br.readLine();
            }catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("IOException caught, just exit");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            s3 = s2;          //<- s3 is referring to  the string obj
                              //which retrieved from pool by last exec of loop

            s2 = s1.intern(); //<- s2 now referring to the string 
                              //obj retrieved from the string pool

            // is s1 == s2 ? // this loop
            if (s1 == s2){
                System.out.println("s1 == s2 they are same string obj");

            }else{
                System.out.println("s1 != s2 they are NOT same string obj");
            }

            // is s2 == s3 ? compared from this loop retrieved(s2) 
            //                               and last loop retrieved(s3)
            if(s2 == s3){
                System.out.println("s2 == s3 they are same string obj");
            }else{
                System.out.println("s2 != s3 they are NOT same string obj");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We run this infinite loop function twice to figure out whether s2 and s3 is the same when we
use the same string from `stdin` as input.

Apparently, when we input `aaa` twice to the loop, s2 and s3 referred to the same string:

```
-> ~/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java TestIntern 
Enter the string
aaa
s1 != s2 they are NOT same string obj
s2 != s3 they are NOT same string obj
Enter the string
aaa
s1 != s2 they are NOT same string obj
s2 == s3 they are same string obj
Enter the string
```

This means, `string.inter()` did add `aaa` to the string pool and return the object, but rather than the string object in the heap which installed by `br.readLine()`, this returned  object is the one in the permanent generation. they are not the same.